# Possibility for overriding left handed operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there in C++ the possibility to override and left handed operator?

For example it is easy override an right handed: As an example:

```
class MyClass{
  public inline MyClass operator*(float &other)
  {
     return MyClass(this->Data * other);
  }
};
```

So I can use something like that:

```
MyClass a = MyClass(...) * 0.4f;
```

What to do, if someone wants to write:

```
MyClass a = 0.4f* MyClass();
```

?

In C# sharp this can be easily done, because there exists class extensions. Does C++ also know some Workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, C++ has free functions, and I wouldn't call it a workaround. Your example is also wrong. You can't pass `0.4f` as a `float&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of class member functions like:

```
ReturnType Function(TypeOfThisClass* this_, TypeOfParam param, ...)
```

(
You use this form in `std::thread` too: (i.e. pass the class ptr as argument)

```
class MyClass { void Function() { ; }; }
....
MyClass myClass;
std::thread(&MyClass::Function, &myClass);
```

)

so your member is:

```
class MyClass{
  ....
  friend MyClass operator*(const MyClass& this_, float &other)
  {
     return MyClass(this_.Data * other);
  };

  /*or MyClass operator*(float &other)
  {
     return MyClass(this->Data * other);
  };, which is the same, except you use it with reference not pointer)*/

  friend MyClass operator*(float &other, const MyClass& this_)
  {
     return this_ * other; //you can use the overloaded op. since it is defined above (first arg is class)
  };
};
```

You should only use the `friend` keyword if you want to access `protected` and `private` data in your class (which should be the case in OOP).

Comment: `friend` allows accessing the private data, as well as the protected.  And the usual idiom here is to define a public `MyClass& MyClass::operator*=( MyClass const& rhs );`, and then define the global `operator*` using it.

Comment: @James Kanze I meant not publicly visible with "protected", edited. Also what is that idiom You're talking about, maybe I can add it to the answer. I just wrote down how the compiler "sees" the functions, so he can better understand what's happening.

Comment: The idiom I'm talking about is the idea that if you support <code>a <i>op</i> b</code>, you should also support <code> a <i>op</i>= b</code>.  The latter _should_ generally be a member (since you don't want conversions on the left hand side), and the former is easily implemented in terms of the latter, and so doesn't even need to be a friend.

Comment: oh I think got it, so `T& operator*=(float rhs){ /**/ return *this; }` inside the class `T` and `T operator*(float lhs, T rhs) { rhs *= lhs; return rhs; }` outside of class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can declare operator overloads as free functions. In your case, since both orderings of the operation have the same meaning, you can delegate one to the other:

```
class MyClass
{
    float data_;

public:
    explicit MyClass(float data) : data_(data) { }   // exposition only

    MyClass operator*(float val) const { return MyClass(data_ * val); }
};

MyClass operator*(float val, MyClass const & x) { return x * val; }
```

Now when you have `MyClass x;` and you say `x * 4`, this uses the member overload, but when you say `4 * x`, it uses the free function, which in turn calls the member function.

Note that by delegating to the opposite operator we can have a plain, free function that doesn't need to know about the implementation of the member function. By constrast, if you wanted to reimplement the free function from scratch, it would need access to the private members of the class, which is typically solved by making the free function a `friend`, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    // as above

    friend MyClass operator*(float val, MyClass const & x)
    {
        return MyClass(x.data_ * val);   // access x's private member
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass a = 0.4f* MyClass();
MyClass a = MyClass(...) * 0.4f;
```

For these to make sense declare operator* as non-member function of class along with single argument constructor.